# Can I boot off a network if I can't modify my router?

Tags: networking, boot, u-boot

My Raspberry Pi needs to be connected to my home router, which unfortunately is a standard router provided by my ISP, so I can't change anything on it. I have another main computer running, which I can use as a server, but (due to wiring contraints) I can't connect the two directly.

Is there a way to boot off network with such a net configuration?

Comment: Usually a standard home router can connect to other devices, eg, a desktop main computer, using wired Ether cable or Wifi, or mobile phones etc, also using WiFi.  Usually if you once entered the username/password etc, every time you boot/switch on computers/mobile phones etc, they will automatically connect.  I am not very sure what you want to do now.  Do you want something like: using a web browser, log on to a web server, say, in your office, and boot the computer at home?  Or just send an email to do that.

Comment: And, why does you want to reboot.  Is it because your computer at home hangs/freezes?

Comment: @tlfong01 My desktop's connected to the router and the Raspberry's connected to the router, but they can't be connected directly to each other (raspberry <-> desktop). So how would I set up remote boot if I can't change the router's DHCP?

Comment: As far as I understand you want to use netbooting, means the devices will get the boot files (kernel) and the root filesystem from a master? I'm a bit confused because a router is not essential for this.